# Inequality of summation of two sequences.

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, inequality

Consider two sequences of positive real numbers $a_1,a_2,\ldots a_n$ and $b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n$ where n is a natural number.

Prove that $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sqrt{a_k^2+b_k^2} \geq \sqrt{(\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k)^2 + (\sum_{k=1}^{n} b_k)^2}$.

My solution: consider n right
triangle joined at their vertices with bases
$a_1,a_2,...a_n$ and heights $b_1,b_2,...b_n$(i.e. they are joined end to end, with all bases parallel to one another).

The LHS of the inequality is sum of their hypotenuse.

By triangle inequality, it's least value would be the line joining the top vertex of the highest right triangle and the bottom vertex of the lowest right triangle, and this value is the RHS.

Hence proved.

Is there any other(non geometrical) solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it should be $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sqrt{a_k^2+b_k^2} \geq \sqrt{(\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k)^2 + (\sum_{k=1}^{n} b_k)^2}$. The proof by geometric is nice. Here is my another proof.

- You just need to prove for case $n=2$ then apply it one by one, for example $n=3$

$$\sum_{k=1}^{3} \sqrt{a_k^2+b_k^2} \geq \sqrt{(a_1+ a_2)^2 + (b_1+ b_2)^2}+\sqrt{a_3^2+b_3^2}\geq \sqrt{(a_1+ a_2+a_3)^2 + (b_1+ b_2+b_3)^2}$$

- For case $n=2$, just squaring both two sides gives you the below equivalent inequality

$$\sqrt{(a_1^2+b_1^2)(a_2^2+b_2^2)} \geq a_1a_2+b_1b_2$$
This is just application of [Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality).